# Boolean AND in prolog returns X=true but the function becomes false

Tags: prolog, boolean

```
and_true(true, true).

and_false(false,true).

and_false(true,false).

and_false(false, false).

g_AND(Y,Z,X):- and_true(Y,Z), X=true.
g_AND(Y,Z,X):- and_false(Y,Z), X=false.
```

The only problem with this is that when I enter g_AND(true,true,X) it gives me 
X=true ;
false

I don't want it to return the false. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

generally you trying to set  "false become true when one of element is false". in your function g_AND(Y,Z,X) false becoming true, because your and_false(Y,Z) statement becoming true after giving false statement into one of variables.

try this code to make 'false become false'

```
and_true(true, true).

g_and(X,Y,Z):-
    and_true(X,Y),and_true(X,Z).
```

this code makes false when one of wariable is false, like natural AND.

Comment: I can't do that because i need the function to work symetrically, so that if I give it g_AND(false,X,false) it will give me X=false, X=true

Answer (score 0):

```
g_AND(true,true,X).
X=true ; 
false
```

The `false.` means that it run out of results. The query `and_true(true, true).` is true and then it backtracked, looking for other statements that `g_AND(true,true,X)` will answer true in your file but it didn't find any, so it returned false. ( In some older versions of Prolog, you might get yes and no)

If you edit your file and add a cut ( ! ):

```
g_AND(Y,Z,X):- and_true(Y,Z), X=true, !.
```

The result will be just `true.`

```
2 ?- g_AND(true,true,X).
X = true.
```

Because, after the first result, the program will stop backtracking (It won't search for other answers).

Comment: I can't do that as well, because if I add the !, when I backtrack i.e g_AND(false,X,false). it will give me only one answer instead of two because of the !

Comment: `g_AND(false,X,false).` Gives me only one answer

Comment: @user3079939, for `g_AND` to give all the answers you need, you need an extra clause: `g_AND(Y,Z,X) :- and_false(Y,Z), X = true.`. Also, if you want prolog to backtrack for other answers, you may have to accept the fact that it might come back false it doesn't find any more solutions. It's the way it works. The only way to avoid it would be if you could structure your predicates such that the last available backtrack on any query is successful.